# ¿Te un Problema con un tema con Sublime Text 4,? me marca así las lineas de código

Tags: sublimetext3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cada vez que intento arreglarlo cambiando el tema me aparece este mensaje, en la consola